# Java socket connection with Swing GUI freezes

Tags: java, swing

I'm pretty new to java, I wanted to make a socket connection between client and server. Without the GUI it works great. But now that i've tried to implement the GUI to the program, the server side interface freezes whenever i try to open a socket, even if the program is still going, so only the interface freezes. Whenever the client finishes the connection, then the server GUI will output everything that was freezed at once. I did some test and i think the metod `server.accept()` but i'm note sure.

**Client.java code**

```
public void waiting(int port) {
    try
    {
        ServerWindow.consolePrint("Server starting up...", 2);
        System.err.print("hello world");
        server=new ServerSocket(port);
        ServerWindow.consolePrint("Server running!", 6);
        ServerWindow.consolePrint("Waiting for a client to connect...", 2);
        client= server.accept();
        ServerWindow.consolePrint("Client connected!", 6);
        
        server.close();
        
        inFromClient=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(client.getInputStream()));
        outToClient=new DataOutputStream(client.getOutputStream());
        communicate();

    }
                   //catch code
}


public void communicate()
{
    
    try {
        outToClient.writeBytes("type /help to display all the commands"+'\n');
        ServerWindow.consolePrint("Waiting for a command from the client...", 2);
        stringReceived=inFromClient.readLine();
        ServerWindow.consolePrint(stringReceived, 1);
        client.close();

      }
              //catch code
```

**Swing GUI code**

```
btnConnect.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                
                //if - else if formatting check
               
                else {
                    server.waiting(Integer.parseInt(TxtPort.getText()));
                }

                   //Input metod for printing string into the console

public static void consolePrint(String strToConsole, int n) {
    SimpleDateFormat formatter= new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss");
    Date date = new Date(System.currentTimeMillis());
    switch (n) {
    case 1: 
        // CLIENT MESSAGE
        StyleConstants.setForeground(style, Color.yellow);
         try {
                    doc.insertString(doc.getLength(), formatter.format(date) + " - Client: ",style);
                } catch (BadLocationException e1) {
                    e1.printStackTrace();
                }
         StyleConstants.setForeground(style, Color.white);
         try {
                    doc.insertString(doc.getLength(), strToConsole + "\n" ,style);
                } catch (BadLocationException e1) {
                    e1.printStackTrace();
                }
         break;
         
    
    case 2:
        // SERVER MESSAGE
        StyleConstants.setForeground(style, Color.cyan);
         try {
                    doc.insertString(doc.getLength(), formatter.format(date) + " - Server: ",style);
                } catch (BadLocationException e1) {
                    e1.printStackTrace();
                }
         StyleConstants.setForeground(style, Color.white);
         try {
                    doc.insertString(doc.getLength(), strToConsole + "\n" ,style);
                } catch (BadLocationException e1) {
                    e1.printStackTrace();
                }
         break;
         
    case 3:
        // CLIENT ERROR MESSAGE
                    //code
         break;
         
    case 4:
        // SERVER ERROR MESSAGE
         try {
                   //code
         break;
         
    case 5:
        // CLIENT SUCCESS MESSAGE
         try {
                  //code
         break;
         
    case 6:
        // SERVER SUCCESS MESSAGE
         try {
                 //code
         break;
        
    default:
        //code
    }
}
```

**MainS.java code**

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        ServerWindow windowGUI = new ServerWindow();
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    windowGUI.frmServer.setVisible(true);
                    windowGUI.frmServer.setResizable(false);
                    windowGUI.frmServer.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }
```

I'm linking 2 image to show that only the UI is freezes

[Before and while the client is connected](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bdhB8.png)

[After the client writes something and so the sockets close, then everything will be outputted at once](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jop2B.png)

Comment: The Socket blocks waiting for data so it needs to be created on a separate Thread. Currently the Socket is created on the EDT so it prevent the GUI from responding to events. Read the Swing tutorial on [Concurrency](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/index.html) for more information. You could use the `SwingWorker`.

Comment: Yeah, as the guy above said, here is a link that shows how it is done: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/introducing-threads-socket-programming-java/